# Liferay : Portlets inside portlet

Tags: liferay, portlet

Is it possible to create a few portlets inside a portlet? I mean a multilevel portlet.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. You can use the [Nested Portlet](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Nested+Portlets+Portlet) to this purpose. This is a layout container for other portlets. You can choose the wanted layout in the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, definately, you can have portlet within portlet.

Liferay provides  taglib, thru which you can easily embed different util portlets (web content display, breadcrumb, navigation etc) within portlet

Answer (score 0):

> ## **NESTED-PORTLET**

Assuming that you are talking about a framework, a platform or something similar, yes, it's possible. Look if your framework have a kind of **Nested-portlet**. I'm using the [liferay](http://www.liferay.com/) platform, and they offer an implementation of  [Nested Portlet](http://www.liferay.com/pt/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Nested+Portlets+Portlet?_36_redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.liferay.com%2Fpt%2Fhome%3Fp_p_id%3D3%26p_p_lifecycle%3D0%26p_p_state%3Dmaximized%26p_p_mode%3Dview%26_3_keywords%3Dnested%2Bportlet%26_3_struts_action%3D%252Fsearch%252Fsearch&_36_pageResourcePrimKey=2963840).

Answer (score -6):

No you can't have portlet within portlet, its similar to having servlet within servlet...

Comment: We can have portlets inside portlets. Liferay has the concept of nested portlets, as limburgie has said