# displaying portlet in another portlet without popup

Tags: java, liferay-6, liferay-aui

Is there any way in to display one portlet in an other portlet ?
Problem i am facing is that i have two portlets in Liferay,i want's to display the complete  second portlet in the reserved div area of the first portlet,so that i can use all the functionality of second portlet  in the first one(I don't want to use popup for this particular scenario). or in other words 
i wants nested portlet
I have Google this but didn't find any helping material ,now my question is this scenario is possible in Liferay?
Any helping will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101247/liferay-portlets-inside-portlet

Comment: but i want how to programatically place a portlet inside another portlet?

Comment: Can you provide more insight in your requirement? May be there is a better & cleaner way to achieve what you're trying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Use nested portlet.

[Emded portlet example](http://sourceforge.net/projects/meeralferay/files/EmbdedPortlet/)

or 
[use web content display portlet inside  you can display portlet](http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2014/03/embedding-portlet-in-web-contentliferay_26.html)

or you can use Liferay Portlet Sharing java script code..

i have small following snippet it will render portlet in div but it wont peforn actions because its static content

the following is example snippet to load portlet in div

```
AUI().use('aui-base','aui-node','aui-dialog','aui-io-request', 'aui-io','liferay-portlet-url','aui-dialog-iframe', function(A) {
var url =Liferay.PortletURL.createRenderURL();    
    url.setPortletId('signinaction_WAR_WatsonSiginInportlet');  
    url.setWindowState('pop_up'); 
    var myAjaxRequest=A.io.request(url.toString(), {
          dataType: 'html',
          autoLoad: false,
          on: {
           success: function() {
            // A.one('#testestDiv').set('innerHTML',"meera");
             document.getElementById("login-portlet-content").innerHTML=this.get('responseData');
             //A.one('#loginBoxDiv').set('innerHTML',this.get('responseData'));
           }
          }
        });

myAjaxRequest.start();
});
```

Comment: thanks Meera prince but i doesn't want it in pop up i want in specific div location